# How do I prove this with the image and kernel?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n \times m$ matrix and let $T_A : \mathbb{R}^m → \mathbb{R}^n$ be the linear transformation $T_A(x)=Ax.$
Also let $B$ be an invertible $m × m$ matrix and let $C$ be an invertible $n × n$ matrix.

How do I prove that $\rm im(T_A) = \rm im(T_{AB})$ and $\ker(T_A) = \ker(T_{CA})$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Prove that $im(T_B) = \mathbb{R}^m$ and $ker(T_C) = \{\mathbf{0}\}$ and use that $T_{AB} = T_A \circ T_B$.